# How to health check hosts over HTTPS behind the load-balancer?

Tags: ssl, load-balancing, healthcheck

I have NGINX serving my site over HTTPS on EC2 hosts behind Elastic Load Balancer. I need to set up a proper health-check in ELB. However, I cannot use https://www.example.com because I need to health-check a HOST, not my site. And on the other side, I cannot use https://ec2host.amazonaws.com because the SSL certificate is valid only for my domain (example.com). So, I ended up using TCP port 80 check which is really the bare minimum.

How do I configure a proper health check in ELB to test whether a given host is delivering my website over HTTPS correctly?

Comment: Is it possible to add in plus of the example.com the IP address to test ?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to accomplish this using an approach like the one described here: http://scottwb.com/blog/2013/10/28/always-on-https-with-nginx-behind-an-elb/.

In NGINX config, I added:

1. A specific location directive for the healthcheck URL ("/healthcheck") that does not
   do any HTTPS enforcement.
2. A redirect if the "X-Forwarded-Proto: https" header does not exist.